# Sweet Alert 2 - Having multiple buttons open different alerts

Tags: sweetalert2

I have a sweet alert that has multiple buttons. When a user clicks on a button it is supposed to open a different alert. I am able to get 1 button to work but that is it. Is this possible with Sweet Alert 2?

Code:

```
$("#swa").on("click", function(e) {
        swal({
          title: '<u><b>Test 1</b></u><p>&nbsp;</p>',
          html:
            '<button id="panel2">Panel 2</button>'+
            '<p>&nbsp;</p>'+
            '<button id="panel3">Panel 3</button>',
          showCloseButton: true,
          showCancelButton: true,
          cancelButtonText: 'Go Back',
          width: '75%'
        })


$("#panel2").on("click", function(e) {
        swal({
          title: '<u><b>Test 2</b></u><p>&nbsp;</p>',
          html:
            'Test 2',
          showCloseButton: true,
          showCancelButton: true,
          cancelButtonText: 'Go Back',
          width: '75%'
        })

$("#panel3").on("click", function(e) {
        swal({
          title: '<u><b>Test 3</b></u><p>&nbsp;</p>',
          html:
            'Test 3',
          showCloseButton: true,
          showCancelButton: true,
          cancelButtonText: 'Go Back',
          width: '75%'
        })
});
});
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mx3s7th7/)

Answer (score 1):

what is happening is that you have your panel3 sweet alert inside your panel2 sweet alert. To fix this just move the `});`

Your javaScript will now be;

```
$("#panel2").on("click", function(e) {
        swal({
          title: '<u><b>Test 2</b></u><p>&nbsp;</p>',
          html:
            'Test 2',
          showCloseButton: true,
          showCancelButton: true,
          cancelButtonText: 'Go Back',
          width: '75%'
        })
    });// <--moved this here

$("#panel3").on("click", function(e) {
        swal({
          title: '<u><b>Test 3</b></u><p>&nbsp;</p>',
          html:
            'Test 3',
          showCloseButton: true,
          showCancelButton: true,
          cancelButtonText: 'Go Back',
          width: '75%'
        })
});
//<--from here
});// I don't think this line is needed
```

By the way the last `});` is not needed unless it relates to code that you haven't posted.

Good luck.